# Flutter shows unexpected keyboard on real Samsung Galaxy S22 device

Tags: android, flutter, android-softkeyboard

I am writing a Flutter app. I want to show a TextField with a keyboard which has numbers, a decimal point, and dashes and slashes. I chose datetime for the keyboardType. I was able to get a keyboard with all the keys I want on a real iPhone, but I got a keyboard with just numbers on a real Samsung Galaxy S22.

I wrote a small app which demonstrates what I am seeing:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Date Time Keyboard Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Date Time Keyboard Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const <Widget>[
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyboard numbers with options

```dart
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)
```

> Optimize for date and time information.

> On iOS, requests the default keyboard.

> On Android, requests a keyboard with ready access to the number keys, ":", and "-".

More info https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType/datetime-constant.html

Comment: `TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)` gives me a decimal point, but I am hoping for a setting that gives me a dash and a slash as well. I don't see those on the Galaxy S22.